# Prevent growing transaction log with INSERT BULK with TABLOCK

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I am working on writing a process which will write to SQL Server from Spark- Scala application. Its generating multiple INSERT BULK per partition of data (as expected), batchsize 100K records.

As I am monitoring the transaction log, I can see its filling up, and I was hoping with INSERT BULK it will not.

Can you please suggest, how I can achieve commits per batch.

Comment: Plase give code examples... see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

When your DB recovery model is set to full, bulk insert will write to the transaction log and the transaction logs will continue to grow. 
You have two options:

1. Change the database recovery model to bulked logged while the data is loaded and reset it to full afterwards
2. Modify your process to backup transaction logs after each batch is loaded (or every few batches)

Comment: I used both database recovery mode to bulk logged as suggested by @camba1 and also used EXEC sp_tableoption tableName, 'table lock on bulk load', 1